Does EF Core supports `ComplexType` under `Owned` property?
I'm using ComplexTypeAttribute for some data columns that I want to group together like:
[ComplexType]
public record TrashData(DateTime? Value)
{
    public Identity By { get; init; } = Identity.Unknown;

    private string _reason = string.Empty;
    public string? Reason
    {
        get => _reason;
        init => _reason = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? string.Empty : value;
    }

    private static readonly TrashData _available = new TrashData((DateTime?)null);
    public static TrashData Available => _available;
}
[ComplexType]
public record Identity(string IdKind = "GUID", string? Value = null)
{
  public static readonly Identity Unknown = new("_","_");
}

I found no issue adding ComplexType inside another one.
But when I added a ComplexType inside an Owned property like the following:
//(I'm using Asp Identity)
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public required UserMetaData MetaData { get; set; } = new(default);
}
[Owned]
public record UserMetaData(string Id)
{
    public TrashData Trashed_ { get; set; } = TrashData.Available;
}

I had build issues after generating migration:

I tried to manually specify this property is complex using Fluent Method like this, but it doesn't seem to exist there:
builder.Entity<User>(e =>
{
//  e.ComplexProperty(x => x.MetaData.Trashed_); // Can call ComplexProperty

    e.OwnsOne(
        x => x.MetaData,
        o =>
        {
            o.WithOwner().HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id).HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
            // o.ComplexProperty(x => x.Trashed_); // Can't call complex property here.
        }
    );
}

So does EF Core 8 support complex type inside owned property, or not yet?
Note: Migration is generated against SQLite.

After some research, .Net 8 and .Net 9 currently don't support complex types under owned properties.
And I think it's not even planned for .Net 10.
So use other methods with owned properties, like nested ones, or don't use it at all.
